# If condition is not working in each function

Tags: jquery

I want to execute the function based on the if condition but it does not work. Please suggest.

```js
$('toggle').each(function(i, e) {
  $('toggle').on('click', function() {
    var selectedid = $('toggle').attr('id');

    if (selectedid == 'Test-selected_' + i) {
      $(this).html('Test').attr('id', '')
        .append("").removeClass('tested');
    } else {
      $(this).html('Tested').attr('id', 'Test-selected_' + i).addClass('tested')
        .append("<span class='toggle-selected'></span>").css('padding', '8px 52px 8px 13px !important;');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_top" id="Test-selected_1" class="toggle clearboth tested" data-upc-tooltip-type="none" title="">Test<span class="toggle-selected"></span></a>
```

Comment: At the first line you don't define weather toggle is if or class selector

Comment: And in the second line instead of say toggle again you have to use this keyword it will refer to that toggle while you use each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code should be like this

```
$('toggle').each(function(i, e){
    $(this).on('click', function(){

    var selectedid =  this.id;


    if(selectedid == 'Test-selected_' + i){
        $(this).html('Test').attr('id', '')
        .append("").removeClass('tested');
    }else{
        $(this).html('Tested').attr('id', 'Test-selected_' + i).addClass('tested')
        .append("<span class='toggle-selected'></span>").css('padding', '8px 52px 8px 13px !important;');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow great, answered after me, with a lot less explanation and get the points for "accepted answer". :') Welcome monday.

Answer (score 3):

```
var selectedid =  $('toggle').attr('id');
/* ... */
$('toggle').on('click', function(){
```

should be

```
 var selectedid =  $(this).attr('id');
/* ... */
$(this).on('click', function(){
```

or even better,

```
 var selectedid =  this.id;
```

The reason the last one is better, is that native javascript almost always is faster. If you do `$(this)` you put the `this` into a jquery function (converting it to a jquery object). then you use `attr()` to loop through the attributes until they're are `id`. `this.id` does neither of those and will just give you the id of `this`.

---

## Lets just turn it into a code review

### Round 1

```
// it's {class}toggle, so (.toggle):
$('.toggle').each(function(i, e) {
  // this has to be 'this', in the each() jloop of jquery, every itteration is one of the elements
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    // you can use the this-> $(this).attr('id'), or even better
    var selectedid = this.id;

    if (selectedid == 'Test-selected_' + i) {
      // if you chain element (which is fine), newline every action to make it more obvious.
      $(this)
        .html('Test')
        .attr('id', '')
        .append("")
        .removeClass('tested');
    } else {
      // if you chain element (which is fine), newline every action to make it more obvious.
      $(this)
        .html('Tested')
        .attr('id', 'Test-selected_' + i)
        .addClass('tested')
        .append("<span class='toggle-selected'></span>")
        .css('padding', '8px 52px 8px 13px !important;');
    }
  });
});
```

### Round 2

```
$('.toggle').each(function(i, e) {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    //var selectedid = this.id; // as we now already have the id value accessable via this.id, we don't need a variable for it

    if (this.id == 'Test-selected_' + i) {
      $(this)
        .html('Test')
        // DONT! change the value if an ID unless you are absolutaly sure you have to.
        // Instead, you can set a data-tested="example" value in html, of via JS:
        .data('tested', '') 
         // Append will be called EVERY TIME. If you do append(""), you will NOT undo the previous append. 
        // .append("") // Append does something like { this.content = this.content + $inputValue }, it'll just add
        // .removeClass('tested') // You can select your elements now via 'toggle[data-tested=""]'
    } else {
      $(this)
        .html('Tested')
        // DONT! change the value if an ID unless you are absolutaly sure you have to.
        // Instead, you can set a data-tested="example" value in html, of via JS:
        .data('tested', 'Test-selected_' + i)
        .append("<span class='toggle-selected'></span>")
        .css('padding', '8px 52px 8px 13px !important;');
    }
  });
});
```

### Round 3

```
$('.toggle').each(function(i, e) {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    if (this.id == 'Test-selected_' + i) {
      // Because it is small now, oneline
      $(this).html('Test').data('tested', '') 
    } else {
      $(this)
        // the rest is now commented of, so oneline
        .html('Tested').data('tested', 'Test-selected_' + i)
        // Every time you loop through this, the span below get appended. EVERY time, so that means multiple spans.
        // Instead, remove this from javascript, and add it to your html and use css to show/hide it
        // .append("<span class='toggle-selected'></span>") 

        //.css('padding', '8px 52px 8px 13px !important;'); // NO JAVASCRIPT STYLING! Use css
    }
  });
});

.toggle{
  padding: 8px 52px 8px 13px !important;
}
.toggle[data-tested=""]{
  padding: 1px; /* here your default styling which I dont know right now */
}
.toggle[data-tested=""] .toggle-selected{
  display: none;
}
```

### Round 4

```
$('.toggle').each(function(i, e) {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    if (this.id == 'Test-selected_' + i) {
      $(this).html('Test').data('tested', '') 
    } else {
      $(this).html('Tested').data('tested', 'Test-selected_' + i)
    }
  });
});
```

And imma stop right here as you've already marked an answer. But this should but you can improve a lot.

Comment: And i think replace $('toggle').on('click', function(){ with $(this).on('click', function(){

Comment: @Martijn, thanks for your answer and deep explanation. I hope I learned lot from your posts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your selector to attach event handler is incorrect, as you are using class prefix `.` i.e. `$('.toggle')`
2. You don't need `.each()` to attach event handler
3. You can use `hasClass('tested')`, and perform conditional operation.

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.hasClass('tested')) {
    self.html('Test')
      .removeClass('tested');
  } else {
    self.html('Tested')
      .addClass('tested')
      .append("<span class='toggle-selected'></span>")
      .css('padding', '8px 52px 8px 13px !importan;');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" target="_top" id="Test-selected_1" class="toggle clearboth" data-upc-tooltip-type="none" title="">Test</a>
```